# flutter local.properties best practices?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am confused about the current flutter project boilerplate. I gather there is a `local.properties` file for project configuration, but all of the "hello world" repos tend to `.gitignore` it.

However, I also found online examples of `android/app/build.gradle` referring to these config values, e.g.

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    }
```

This confuses me, since `minSdkVersion` is appropriate to check in, as the entire software team should be on the same page.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? I'm having the same exact dilema.